# Using Visio in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: visio

We don't have access to Business data categorie when creating web part (visio web access) Do i need "Visio Web Access" to work with visio web parts Sharepoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a Visio Graphic Service in Central Administration to make use of Visio Web Parts in SharePoint 2013.

[image]